# How to get week number in month of given date. Week start will be Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Query to get week number in month for a given date. Week start will be Monday.

EX: Based on date 2023-04-28 Week No need to be 4.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '20230428'

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, @DATE)  
     - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,@DATE), 0)) 
     + 1 AS WEEK_OF_MONTH
```

WEEK_OF_MONTH is returning as 5, but the expected need to be 4

Comment: What happens if you remove the + 1

Comment: For `2023-04-01` and  `2023-04-02`, what should the week number be? They occur before the first Monday in April.

Comment: @ahmed: It is 5.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes a small matter if you have a `Calendar Table` ... many examples.  Here is a scaled down version

**Example --- Create Calendar Table**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '1980-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2525-12-31'
Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1) 
       D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
 Into  Calendar
 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2,master..spt_values n3
```

**Usage**

```
Declare @D date='2023-04-28' 

Select count(*)
 From  Calendar
 Where D between format(@D,'yyyy-MM-01') and @D
   and datename(WEEKDAY,D)='Monday'
```

**Results**

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```sql
Declare @Date DateTime
Declare @FirstDate DateTime
Declare @FirstMonday DateTime

Set DateFirst 1

SET @Date = '20230428'
Set @FirstDate = DateAdd(day, 1 - DatePart(Day, @Date), @Date)
Set @FirstMonday = DateAdd(day, (7 + 1 - DatePart(weekday, @FirstDate)) % 7, @FirstDate)
-- Check and offset by one month if Date belongs to the last week of the previous month.
Set @FirstMonday = IIf(DateDiff(day, @Date, @FirstMonday) > 0, DateAdd(month, -1, @FirstMonday), @FirstMonday)

Select 
    @Date As TheDate, 
    Datepart(weekday, @Date) As TheWeekday, 
    @FirstDate As FirstDate, 
    @FirstMonday As FirstMonday, 
    1 + DateDiff(day, @FirstMonday, @Date) / 7 As WeekOfMonth
```